# maven "Compilation failure" but no issue displayed

Tags: maven-compiler-plugin

When running `mvn install` the build fails intermittently with `Compilation failure`, particuarly at `AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1165` however no warnings or errors are displayed. Setting `<verbose>true</verbose>` in the maven-compiler-plugin has no effect.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.209 s (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-13T16:49:32Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 147M/611M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project PROJECTNAME: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project PROJECTNAME: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1165)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.multithreaded.MultiThreadedBuilder$1.call (MultiThreadedBuilder.java:196)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to invoke `javac` manually with the same arguments and the following error was output

```
The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type.map(Type.java:220)
        ...
```

The issue can be solved by increasing the stack size to say 4 MB with `-J-Xss4m`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-J-Xss4m</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The root cause of the issue was a 3000-line Map field initialization. So the real solution was to move that data to a file.

Similar to this issue: https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2234

Answer (score 0):

pass argument "-verbose" to compilerArgs as shown below to get details of the failure.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        <!-- false means true here -->
        <useIncrementalCompilation>true</useIncrementalCompilation>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-J-Xss512m</arg>
            <arg>-J-noverify</arg>
            <arg>-verbose</arg>
            <arg>-Xlint:all,-options,-path</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```